# How do you "Mavenize" a project using Intellij?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have seen many posts about using eclipse to Mavenize a project.  Is there a easy way to do that in IntelliJ?  From what I understand about "Mavenize", it's just add some xml in pom.xml and the directory structure is in src/main/java, src/main/test ....

Comment: possible duplicate of [IntelliJ - Convert a Java project/module into a Maven project/module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642456/intellij-convert-a-java-project-module-into-a-maven-project-module)

Answer (score 107, accepted):

For those that benefit from a visual, as I did:

[image]

Essentially, just right-click on the folder. In this example, it's called `StackOverFlow` and choose `Add Framework Support` and then check the `Maven` box. Please note, that this option only exists when you have created a class within the `src` folder.

Comment: It is really difficult to find. Thanks a lot :) .

Comment: the you this is realy dificult to find.

Comment: Thank you!! So easy this way

Answer (score 5):

Right-click on the module, select "Add framework support...", and check the "Maven" technology.
(This also creates a pom.xml for you to modify.)

Answer (score 2):

Go to .iml and in the component change the  tag to the following

```
<module org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsManager.isMavenModule="true" type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in 2016.3.1 version:
Right click on project -> go to the Maven menu ->  show effective POM

Answer (score 0):

Following steps will help you to add maven support for your project.

1. Right click on the module
2. Select Add Framework Support
3. Select Maven from the options on the left and click OK

Now the IDEA will create a default `pom.xml` to the project selected and creates standard `maven` project structure.

Open the created `pom.xml` file and edit the `groupId`, `artifactId` and `version` as per your requirement since the values will be automatically created when converted to `maven` project.

Afterwards, dependencies can be added into the `pom.xml`. Every time you change the POM, IntelliJ IDEA displays a popup suggesting to import your changes. You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26099526/how-to-disable-maven-auto-import-automatically-in-intellij-idea/72012349#72012349) to enable/ disable auto import if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Now, even adding Framework support I cannot auto-generate the structure of Maven project (`src/main/java`, `src/test/java`, etc.).

But, Intellij has a fallback: right click the project, "New" - "Folder", you will see those 4 dirs as hints. Just select them and they are generated following the convention. Kind of automated. I am satisfied already.

Here I only have 3 because I don't want to delete my `src/main/java`. But at first there were 4. You get the idea.

[image]