# How to disable Maven auto import automatically in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I believe this setting might be causing IntelliJ IDEA to behave slowly. I used to get a popup and finally clicked 'do this automatically', and now it is on, but I want to turn it off again. How can I disable Maven 'auto import'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intellij IDEA and Maven, disable reading pom.xml on every small change, even without a save](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26099685/intellij-idea-and-maven-disable-reading-pom-xml-on-every-small-change-even-wit)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Although above answers are correct. I have observed that above option is not available on IntelliJ **2020.2** version. So, there you need to go **Settings** -> **Build Tool** -> Check **"Reload projects after changes in the build scripts"** -> check **"Any changes"** [image]

Answer (score 55):

Uncheck `Project Settings | Maven | Importing | Import Maven projects automatically`.

For **IDEA 14+** it's under `Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Importing | Import Maven projects automatically`.

For **IDEA 2020+**, open `Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools`  and check `"Reload projects after changes in the build scripts"` and `"Any changes"`

Comment: This worked for me, but I did have to restart intelliJ in order for the editor to stop behaving slowly.

Comment: I don't see this option in IntelliJ 2020.1 (Linux). Any update to this answer, please?

Comment: This has changed in version 2020.1 dramatically. see https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/01/intellij-idea-2020-1-eap/?_ga=2.166486142.1328458743.1589984167-1329951468.1589984167#maven_and_gradle_importing_updates and https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360007973600-maven-auto-import

Comment: Please up vote this issue to get auto import back! https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-235459

Answer (score 8):

Go to Intellij's Settings and navigate to `Build, Execution, Deployment -> Maven -> Importing ->` uncheck `Import Maven projects automatically`.

Answer (score 5):

For me (IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.1 on Ubuntu 12) this setting was in `Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven > Importing > [X] Import Maven projects automatically`.

In case it moves again, or you want to get to it quickly, the Maven settings are also findable through a general search by double-tapping Shift and then typing `maven`, which is how I found it this time--I think the setting location in IDEA must have been moved since the other answers were posted.

Comment: double-tapping shift is helpful to me. Thx

Answer (score 2):

Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Importing -> Import Maven projects automatically

Answer (score 0):

Since it is regarding `InteliJ IDEA 13`, follow these steps to **disable auto import** `maven`.

```
Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Importing -> UNTICK Import Maven projects automatically
```

This steps also works for `InteliJ IDEA 14` upwards excluding `InteliJ IDEA 20` and above.