# Intellij IDEA and Maven, disable reading pom.xml on every small change, even without a save

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-13

This is causing intellij to become slow and freeze up which is annoying as ****.

It appears as if it analyses other files similar to pom.xml causing freezes on other places as well.

Can this be disabled?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable Maven auto import automatically in IntelliJ IDEA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26099526/how-to-disable-maven-auto-import-automatically-in-intellij-idea)

Comment: @sfat The solution in the other question and in this one do not solve this error. It still occurs. The other question specifically asks for disabling of maven auto import. This one to disable the analyzis of the  pom file which is not resolved by any answer so far.

Comment: It should do this on save only, not for every character change.

Comment: Why did you post the same question twice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Windows Operating system, Press `Ctrl + Alt + S`, or `File\Settings\` **Project Settings** section.
in section `Maven`:
* Uncheck: `Import Maven project automatically`.
* Section `Generated sources folder:`, Choose `Don't Detect`.
[image]
* Section `Runner`: Uncheck `Run in background`.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can disable option in

Settings -> Maven -> Importing -> Import Maven projects automatically

(see [intellij docs](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/maven-importing.html))

And then everytime you want to reimport the pom do it in [Maven Projects tool window](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/maven-projects-tool-window.html)