# Maven variables set after running goals cannot be resolved in IDEA

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have variables in my parent POM which are set during pre-build maven plugin goals such as **buildnumber:create** and **build-helper:parse-version**. In Intellij IDEA, these variables show '*cannot resolve symbol*' warnings in the IDE and the pom.xml is red (disaster!). The build still works as the goals are run every time.

Examples of such symbols which cannot be resolved are: ${parsedVersion.majorVersion} ${parsedVersion.minorVersion}

Eclipse manages to find a way round this, I believe, using a section in the pom for plugin management to execute the goals at at on configuration/increment:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            <pluginExecutions>
                <pluginExecution>
                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <versionRange>[1.0-beta-1,)</versionRange>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <action>
                        <execute>
                            <runOnConfiguration>true</runOnConfiguration>
                            <runOnIncremental>true</runOnIncremental>
                        </execute>
                    </action>
                </pluginExecution>
             </pluginExecutions>
        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Is there any way to do the equivalent in intellij so the symbols are resolved in the editor?

Cheers

Comment: Those configuration you are using is for Eclipse M2E and will not influence IntelliJ IDEA ...?

Comment: That's right, the pluginExecution is for m2e, let me expand the snippet..

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/37444282/65839

Comment: I think you're right, thanks for that. Looks like there's not a proper solution to it, then. Now to decide on the lesser of two evils..