# Intellij: skipTests flag not recognized

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I got the following maven configuration in my pom.xml The skipTests variable is highlighted red by Intellij Ultimate 2018.1 as

> Cannot resolve symbol 'skipTests'

But why? This is a common maven environmental variable.

```
<build>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <!-- exec yarn -->
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      ...
      <execution>
        <id>yarn-test</id>
        <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <executable>yarn</executable>
          <skip>${skipTests}</skip>
          <arguments>
            <argument>test</argument>
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to restart Intellij Idea, sometimes the errors disappear only when you restart it. If that doesn't work, try to change the version of your Maven.

EDIT

Check this link, I think that will help you [How to disable pom.xml validation in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37444282/how-to-disable-pom-xml-validation-in-intellij-idea)

Comment: Restart does not help. What about the maven version? The error comes from Intellij inspection, not from maven. Could the reason be that skipTests is not a general maven flag but only the surefire-plugin flag? And that Intellij just does not know what it is?

Comment: Thanks, so it is kind of Intellij drawback.

Comment: something like that, if it helped accept my answer, glad I could help

Answer (score 4):

I solved the issue by putting the intellij ignore comment

```
<!--suppress MavenModelInspection -->
```

on that particular pom line.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was to put a default value in the properties section as well:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <skip.ut>false</skip.ut>
</properties>
```

An then skip.ut not has been red anylonger in the plugin section of my surefire plugin:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <skipTests>${skip.ut}</skipTests>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```