# How to force IntelliJ IDEA to show files/folders while resolving maven dependencies in background

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Whenever I try to import(using File -> Open -> pom.xml) an existing maven project into IntelliJ IDEA, it starts resolving dependencies immediately but wouldn't show the source code(files/folders) until the fetching process completes.

I want to override this behavior but couldn't get any info over the web, is there a way to achieve this...?
I want to see source code files right after import while maven dependency resolution and indexing is happening in background .

Thanks

Comment: Try disabling maven auto import. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26099526/how-to-disable-maven-auto-import-automatically-in-intellij-idea

Comment: IDE needs to set up the project structure and set the correct folders to sources/resources. it takes this information from Maven pom.xml file, so until this information is not extracted by IDE the project structure can not be correctly set. A related request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-217195