# How to manage project dependencies using Maven?

Tags: java, linux, maven

This is probably a newbie quesiton, but I'm a newbie when it comes to Java and the Maven documentation is tough to work through and all seems to be written for Maven experts.  I'm trying to install a driver in a Java project.  I've got a project with code that works (ie, I don't want to torch what I already have) and maven is installed and up-to-date.  I know the dependency XML to add to pom.xml, but I don't know where to start to create a pom.xml file.

I tried to run 'mvn install' a couple of times, but I don't see the driver anywhere so I can't reference it with my java build path.

What's the best way to proceed?

Comment: paste the error. try this: `mvn clean install -X`

Comment: no error.  I'm asking how to get started.

Comment: just  paste entire output when you run `mvn install` whatever it is. It is not clear to me what you mean by "driver" here. Do you not see JDK in path? Do you not see mvn in path? Is there a missing dependency. Question is vague.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all check if the maven is installed - `mvn --version` in the command line.

If not - follow the guide - http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

To create a `pom.xml` manually is not a good point if you use IDE - just create a new Maven project (for example in Idea or Eclipse). This way you will avoid errors with some required configurational tags missing. Then add the needed dependency in the `dependencies` tag in `pom.xml`

Actually, one of the best tutorials about maven is http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/maven-tutorials/ - there are a lot of topics. Choose the desired one.

If you use `Eclipse IDE` just follow this tutorial to convert your project to the Maven project - [Convert Existing Eclipse Project to Maven Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449461/convert-existing-eclipse-project-to-maven-project) - and delete the `pom.xml` created by you before that. Be sure to have the `m2eclipse` plugin installed in the IDE.

This is for the conversion in the `Intellij idea` - [IntelliJ - Convert a Java project/module into a Maven project/module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642456/intellij-convert-a-java-project-module-into-a-maven-project-module)

Comment: (i have maven installed, most recent version 3.something) so basically what you are saying is that if i've already got a project, I need to start over?

Comment: no, not really. You can -convert- your project to the maven one. What IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm using eclipse on ubuntu, and if it's significantly easier to start a new project I can.