# Making automatic jar through windows batch script with intellij IDEA's codebase

Tags: java, batch-file, jar, intellij-idea

I have a jar **codebase** (developed and successfully compiled in Intellij IDEA) **without class files**. I want to make jar with that codebase through windows batch-script only. Please help me to make the jar automatically without opening it in any IDE or any manual operation.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Do you plan to write batch script ofr windows or linux/unix based machine?

Comment: Why not use ant or gradle?

Answer (score 1):

You generally do that using build tools like Ant, Maven. Maven is quite more popular these days.

Convert your intellij project into an Maven project like this ([IntelliJ - Convert a Java project/module into a Maven project/module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642456/intellij-convert-a-java-project-module-into-a-maven-project-module)), and then execute `call mvn clean package` from your windows script to build the jar. The jar will be located under ${project.dir}/target