# How to convert a scala project to use a pom.xml file?

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea

I have an existing scala application in IntelliJ that is just a single main.scala file at this point.

I want to convert this project so it uses maven so I can add dependancies/libraries.

How do I do this?  I tried adding a pom.xml file but it doesn't seem like it has identified the file as a maven pom file as the icon hasn't changed.

Do I have to convert to project somehow to a maven project?  If so, how?

Also, if I create a maven module project, it defaults to Java and I don't know how to convert it to scala?

Comment: Not sure why this is marked as duplicate, this question is about scala while https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642456 is about Java, which is also mentioned in the question.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried, from the command line (cd to pom.xml's folder):

mvn idea:idea