# Setting up Jenkins to build IntelliJ-project (using BitBucket)

Tags: java, maven, ant, intellij-idea, jenkins

I am trying to set up a Jenkins Server to build my IntelliJ-project (using BitBucketfor VCS (git)).

I have been able to set up IntelliJ to build correctly locally, and I am pushing it to bitbucket. I have also managed to set up Jenkins to get the code from BitBucket.

The problems to actually doing the build process itself, my problem being that I can't seem to figure out how to set it up with Ant / Maven, which I have never used before.

Any good suggestions?

PS: I am still searching for tutorials or anything that gives some help towards achieving this, and will be updating if I find something that helps.

Comment: You have to make a choice : Ant or Maven ?
When you've done that it will be easier to help you.
There's a lot of resources comparing Ant, Maven (and the newest one Gradle)

Comment: Maybe this is helpful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642456/intellij-convert-a-java-project-module-into-a-maven-project-module

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins can fetch the code from the repository to its workspace, but it cannot build it for you. You need to give him the tool to do that. Popular choices are Maven/Ant/Gradle to handle project building for you.

You need to refer to the proper documentation for either [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) or [Ant](https://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html). The process is too broad and project-specific for me to go into details here, but Jenkins provides nice integration for both. If you know neither of them, I think I'd suggest Maven, but it's up to personal preferences and project needs.

You should first try to build project locally. Once you acomplish that, doing that with Jenkins shouldn't be a problem.