# how to add program arguments for maven command line project in intellij?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I am new in intellij. I would like to add program arguments for my maven command line application so that they can be used in `main(String[] args)` method, such as: `-pg 541`, which specified some method to be triggered in my main function.

I was tried to do it using Maven configuration (Run/Debug Configurations) by adding arguments directly in Command line section but it didn't succeed.

I tried also JUnit which runs Maven project but the program arguments section was disabled.

Here is a snapshot of what I tried.

**using junit configuration:**

[image: using junit configuration]

**using maven configuration:**

[image: using maven configuration]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ - Convert a Java project/module into a Maven project/module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642456/intellij-convert-a-java-project-module-into-a-maven-project-module)

Comment: The project is already maven! I do not need to convert a project into maven. I need a possible way to pass program argument to main function.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

JUnit tests are executed via the test runner framework, your `main` method is not called at all by JUnit, therefore you can't supply program arguments this way.

To pass the arguments to the application via its `main` method you have to use [Application Run/Debug configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/run-debug-configuration-application.html) type in IDEA.

If you want to pass parameters to the unit tests, consider using VM Options field instead, like `-Dparam=value` and in the test method you can read it with `String value = System.getProperty("param");`

Maven supports it as well using [argLine](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#argLine) in some unit test plugins.