# How to add arguments for maven springboot:run?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, spring-boot-maven-plugin

This is a possible duplicate to: [how to add program arguments for maven command line project in intellij?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42274563/how-to-add-program-arguments-for-maven-command-line-project-in-intellij)

While the answer was valid 2017, I struggle 2023.

I was forced to take an App under maintenance that uses Springboot and Maven. I am not really familiar with maven so far and Springboot just stopped being magic.

The App needs an argument, but I have no idea how to set this argument in IntelliJ probably to run/debug configurations. I am talking about the argument read by

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

Thanks so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged the question with `#intellij-idea`, I'm assuming you are looking for the solution that is specific to the IDE.

Modify Options | Program Arguments:

[image: Program arguments]

[image: Arguments]

If you are looking for a Maven-specific solution, ask a question without IDE tags.